# How to get rid of apostrophes in a CSV but keep the leading 0?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV where I need to get rid of the leading '(apostrophe) in python WITHOUT changing the format of the text before it.

I have tried using the following:

```py
with open("file.csv") as infile, open("file.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace("'", ""))
```

However, this is not a solution as the leading 0's are still needed for character validation and this get's rid of it.

Comment: this doesn't remove any zero, leading or otherwise. How do you observe this issue?

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting csv? Many programs like Excel or Libreoffice Calc will trim those leading zeroes automatically as it assumes a column type, this can be avoided by setting the column type on open or using a plain text editor to open the resulting csv.

Comment: *Why* do you want to remove the quotes? The quote is not part of the data, it is a conventional indication that the data is a string not a number, and so any leading zeroes must be preserved. Any program that reads the csv file will interpret it correctly (that is, will treat just the value *inside* the quotes as data) if you tell it that your string delimiter is apostrophe, not double quote.

Comment: I'm currently opening these is a standard excel csv format. I believe i have a limitation for formatting as the receivers of the files need the data to be produced in this specific way.

Comment: I understand that the receiving program does not like the data as it is. I do not agree with your diagnosis of the problem. If the `csv` is an Excel dump then it may have a leading (not enclosing) single quote that indicates a string rather than a number (a purely spreadsheet convention). If you simply remove that quote then the receiving program will assume the data is a number, which is not what you want. In that case tell Excel at export time to put double quotes around strings. The receiving program is unlikely to have a problem with that. Consider adding a small sample of your input data.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing there that removes `0`. But it removes all single quotes, not just leading ones. Use `lstrip()` to remove leading characters.

```
outfile.write(line.lstrip("'"))
```

Comment: lstrip is still returning the leading ', is there any way where I can keep the data without the apostrophe?
example:  return 0000355 instead of '0000355

Comment: Are you sure it's a `'` character, not a curly quote `’`?